# com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: fetch, react-native, react-native-ios

am using React's fetch() method to login in to my service.
So far I have done as below, you can check out my stuffs :

```
_callApiForLogin = () => {
ToastAndroid.show('Logging In...', ToastAndroid.SHORT);

let data = new FormData();
data.append('username', "sssss");
data.append('password', "123456");
data.append('device_token', "hjkhjkhjkkksdkjhkjhksdsfs");
data.append('device_type', "2");

fetch('https://612.33.196.54/~yes/master/api/web/login', {

  method: 'POST',

  body: data,

}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    ToastAndroid.show('Logging In...', responseJson);
    if (responseJson.status === '1') {
      ToastAndroid.show('Logging Successful' + responseJson, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    }
    return responseJson.status;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  }
```

But, getting below error in response.

**Error : 
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Double**

The response coming from the service is as below :

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
        "id": "551",
        "first_name": "sssss",
        "last_name": "lastname",
        "email": "ja@gmail.com",
        "username": "sssss",
        "password": "e10adc83e",
        "photo": "",
        "birthdate": "1963-02-13",
        "gender": "",
        "token": "1234567890",
        "device_type": "2"
    },
    "message": "Successful Login"
}
```

What might be the issue ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using a `React Native Module` to show the `Toast`  i.e. `ToastAndroid` hence *com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap* in your error. The `show()` method as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toastandroid#show) accepts a `duration` which is converted into a double, as its second argument, in this case, you are passing `responseJson` which is an object thus it cannot be cast to a double.

Comment: Thanks sir, How can I done such a silly mistake.. btw. its working now.